# Measurability in a Bochner space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I'd like to prove a function is in the Bochner space $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n))$. I'm having issues because most conditions I've found for ensuring measurability require pointwise convergence of some sequence of either simple or compactly supported continuous functions. The function $f$ is a limit of a sequence in a different space, and it specifically does not converge in $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n))$ (nor in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for tixed $t$). I have a different property and I'm wondering if it can be used instead. Let $\chi:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function of the unit ball. For all $r>0$, I have that
$$\chi(x/r)f(t)(x)\in L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n))$$
with norm uniformly bounded over $r$. Is it possible to use this family to show $f\in L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n))$? If not, do you have a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $T=1$ and $n=1$. Write every $t\in [0,1]$ as binary representation
$$
t = \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{t,k} 2^{-k}
$$
with $b_{t,k} \in \{0,1\}$.

Now define $f$ by
$$
f(t,x):= \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{t,k} \chi_{[k,k+1)}(x),
$$
which has to be understood as
$$
f(t,x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x\in [k,k+1) \text{ and } b_{t,k}=1,\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\|f(t_1) - f(t_2) \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)} = 1 \quad \forall t_1\ne t_2
$$
and $\{ f(t): \ t\in [0,1]\}$ is not separable in $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, and hence $f:[0,1]\to L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is not measurable.

However, the function $f_r$ defined by
$$
(x,t) \mapsto \chi(x/r) f(t,x)
$$
is measurable, in fact $f_r$ is constant on intervals of length $2^{-(k+1)}$ with $k<r\le k+1$.